# Find $\det(A)$ if $p(\lambda) = -\lambda^3 + 2\lambda^2 - \lambda-5$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I'm having some trouble solving the following:

> Let $A$ be an $3\times 3$ matrix with real entries. If the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is: $$p(\lambda) = -\lambda^3 + 2\lambda^2 - \lambda-5$$
> What is the value of $\det(A)$

I know that the determinant of the matrix is the product of all the roots of the characteristic polynomial, the thing is that I don't know how I can find them in this example. Is there another way of solving this?

Comment: The answer is $-5$, not $5$ @user376343

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the $-1$ coefficient of $\lambda^3$ proves the source's definition of $A$'s characteristic polynomial is $\det(A-\lambda I)$ rather than $\det(\lambda I-A)$. So $\det A=p(0)$ is the constant term, $-5$.

Answer (score 1):

If you recall that a polynomial can be written as the product of terms $x-x_i$, you directly see that

$$
p(\lambda)=C\cdot(\lambda-\lambda_1)\cdot(\lambda-\lambda_2)\cdot(\lambda-\lambda_3)\\
=C\cdot(\lambda^3+(\ldots)\cdot\lambda^2+(\ldots)\cdot\lambda-\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3)\\
=-1\cdot(\lambda^3-2\lambda^2+\lambda+5)\\
\Rightarrow \lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3=-5
$$

Please note that for characteristis polynomials the highest order coefficient and therefore the constant $C$ will always be $-1$.

Comment: So, if the polynomial was $p(\lambda) = -5\lambda^3 + 2\lambda^2 - \lambda-5$, $\det(A)$ would still be $5$? or would that change the answer?

Comment: No, you need to factor out the coefficient of the highest order term. I updated the answer. However for characterists polynomials it will always be a $1$ for the leading coefficient so your characteristic polynomial doesnt make sense.

Comment: The answer is $-5$, not $5$

Comment: You are right. Just for the sake of completeness I corrected my answer.